# Finding variance of a subset of data from a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot, variance

I have a scatterplot of x versus y.  I have drawn an abline down the middle of the plot.  I want to calculate the variance of the points on the left of the abline and I want to calculate the variance of the points on the right of the abline.  This is most likely a relatively simple problem, but I'm struggling to find a solution.  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
    x = rnorm(100,mean=12,sd=2)
    y = rnorm(100,mean=20,sd=5)
    data = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
    plot(x=x,y=y,type="p")
    abline(v=12,col="red")
```

Comment: Please read: [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Take a look at `?resid` - `resid(lm(y ~ x)) > 0` for instance for defining groups on either side of a line of best fit. Maybe - `tapply(y, resid(lm(y~x))>0, var)` but you're going to have to clarify exactly what it is you want.

Comment: I apologize, I have included some example code.  When looking at the plot, my goal is to take points that are to the left of the red line and find the variance.  Then I want to find the variance of the points on the right side of the line so that I can compare the variances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sample code you have a vertical line `v = 12`. Your data points `(x, y)` are split into two groups as `x < 12` and `x >= 12`. It is straightforward to do something like:

```
var(y[x < 12])
var(y[x >= 12])
```

But we can also use a single call to `tapply`:

```
tapply(y, x < 12, FUN = var)
```

---

More generally if you have a line `y = a * x + b`, where `a` is slope and `b` is intercept, your data points `(x, y)` will be split into two groups: `y < a * x + b` (below the line) and `y >= a * x + b` (above the line), so that you may use

```
tapply(y, y < a * x + b, FUN = var)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I knew it not be as difficult as I was making it.